# How to count distinct rows and get data of the row and count of it as a second column

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a data

```
ID
AAA
ABB
ABC
BDS
BRD
CXD
DCU
ETS
```

I would like to count distinct to a first letter rows and get the number of their appearance to the right. Sorry I  know I am not a very good user of a technical language, but I am new to SQL and English is not my first language.
So by script I would like to return

```
ID  Total
A  3
B  2
C  1
D  1
E  1
```

I have tried

```
select left(id,1), count(left(id,1) as Total 
from Places 
group by Id 
order by Total desc;
```

, but it didn't work. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MySQL and (MS) SQL Server are not the same thing. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2):

```
select left(id,1), count(*) as Total 
from Places 
group by left(id,1)
order by Total desc;
```

Comment: ps. if you want to count the distinct IDs (i.e. if data has two  `AAA` entries and one `AAB` you want the `A` count to be `2`) replace `count(*)` with `count(distinct id)`

Answer (score 0):

Is this you need?

```
declare @t table(val varchar(10))
insert into @t
select 'AAA' union all 
select 'ABB' union all 
select 'ABC' union all 
select 'BDS' union all 
select 'BRD' union all 
select 'CXD' union all 
select 'DCU' union all 
select 'ETS'
select left(t1.val,1) as id ,count(t1.val) as total from @t as t1 left join
(
select distinct right(val,1) as val  from @t 
) as t2 on t1.val =t2.val
  group by left(t1.val,1)
```

Result is

```
id   total
---- -----------
A    3
B    2
C    1
D    1
E    1
```